# Python - Determine if class method is overriden or inherited

Tags: python, inheritance

Is there any way to check if a class method is an override or inherited from base class if the possible override was not marked as such during implementation?

```
class Super(object):
  def method(self, x, y):
    v = x + y
    return v

class Sub1(Super):
  def method(self, x, y):
    v = x + y + 10 # the calcs are irrelevant, not a reliable way to determine if inherited
    return v

class Sub2(Super):
  def ownMethod(self):
    return 'something'
```

Would there be anything distinguishing about the methods `Sub1.method` vs `Sub2.method` or calls to them that would distinguish them as inherited from `Super`?

Answer (score 2):

At instance level

```
>>> getattr(Sub1().__class__, 'method')
<function __main__.Sub1.method(self, x, y)>

getattr(Sub2().__class__, 'method')
>>> <function __main__.Super.method(self, x, y)>
```

At class level

```
>>> getattr(Sub1, 'method')
<function __main__.Sub1.method(self, x, y)>

>>> getattr(Sub2, 'method')
<function __main__.Super.method(self, x, y)>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that `Sub2.method` is exactly the same function object as `Super.method`, while `Sub1.method` is a different object:

```
>>> Sub2.method
<function Super.method at 0x7f9601345280>
>>> Super.method
<function Super.method at 0x7f9601345280>
>>> Sub2.method is Super.method
True
>>> Sub1.method is Super.method
False
```

So if you know the superclass, you could try checking like this.